# property find does not exists on type Posts[]

Tags: javascript, typescript

I created the following interface:

```
export interface Post {
    _id: string;
    admin: Admin;
    comments: PostComment[];
    createdAt: Date;
    modified: boolean;
    text?: string;
    desc?: string;
    photoPath?: string;
}
```

But when I used this:

```
const post = posts.find((e: Post) => e._id === cmnt.postId);
```

it throws error, 'Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Post[]'.. How to fix this...

Answer (score 3):

You need to set your compiler `target` to ES6 in tsconfig.